# Titan: Both query is same?

Tags: titan

Let say I have following things

```
V1.setProperty("category","C1");
V1.setProperty("city","City1");
```

QUERY for `vertices having city city1`:

```
 v.query().has("category","c1").has("city","city1").vertices();
```

same thing in different way:

```
V1.setProperty("category","C1");
V1.setProperty("C1_city","City1");
```

QUERY for `vertices having city city1`:

```
v.query().has("C1_city","city1").vertices();
```

assume `category` `city` and `C1_city` is both index. Are both query same performancewise?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say that they are the same from a performance perspective.  In the first case, Titan will only use the index from `category` and will not use the `city` index (it will just iterate all `c1` vertices and then filter on `city`.  Therefore, I guess I would expect that the second query would be faster as it is finding exactly what you are looking for completely through the index.

Comment: does the same thing will happen with `label` e.g. `label("city").has("category","c1")`.

Comment: you are getting `label` for free as it is handled as a special case within Titan, so the benefits of indices on edge properties would be in addition to the benefits on a property key.

Comment: I didn't get your point say if I have `city` label with `category` `c1` `c2`...`cn`, and do the query `label("city").has("category","c1")` will it iterate all `city` label and then filter `c1` as you said in case of vertex indices.?

Comment: 'label' refers to an edge not a vertex (at least until Tinkerpop3), so i assumed you were doing some kind of edge based iteration in which case, what i said in the comment above applies.